# Enumerating supplementary groups in a C Program

Tags: c, linux, gnu

I'm wanting to get a list of supplementary groups for the user by sending a request through NSS. To my reckoning, the following program should let me enumerate all the groups (so I can then compare members):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct group *groupStruct;

int main(){

        setgrent();

        while ( groupStruct=getgrent() )
           printf("%s\n", groupStruct->gr_name);

        endgrent();

        return 0;
}
```

I'm basing this assumption on this part of the source code for `id` that gets executed with `id -Gn` (since that's the functionality I want to replicate). Looking at that it looks like it gets the list of groups via `getugroups (0, NULL, username, gid)` with `getugroups()` being defined in another file (essentially the same code found [here](https://github.com/hpc/Parallel-coreutils/blob/master/lib/getugroups.c)). It looks like that is going through the same setgrent()/getgrent() procedure as above, so my feeling is that my simple program ought to enumerate the system's groups (instead, it only does the groups in `/etc/group` but I have winbind on this machine and `id -Gn` pulls in the winbind groups the user is a member of).

Comment: Your title says "gentent"; did you mean "getent"?

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't even an accurate title for what my question was. Updated to something closer to the mark. Still interested in knowing precisely what the different is, though.

Comment: I managed to miss the question when it was asked, but your solution is more or less what's required.  I could give you a long disquisition on  how multiple entries with the same group number but different group names work, and how the same name with different group numbers works, and so on and so forth, but it probably isn't worth it.  The `getgroups()` function returns the supplementary group ID numbers; you can use `getgrgid()` to find the name corresponding to each such group.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler any ideas on what I could do to cover the case of someone actually having group ID number "0" in their supplementary groups? I know it's a corner case, but I still feel like the program ought to account for it.

Comment: Group 0 has various names on various systems (`root` on Linux, `wheel` on Mac OS X, `system` on AIX, IIRC), but does not provide any special powers to the user beyond those inherent in it being a group (so that users belonging to the group can modify files or directories where the group has write permission).  You can have a user who belongs to an anonymous group if it is listed in the password file (where the primary group is listed by number, not name).  However, there's nothing else special about group 0, unlike UID 0.

Comment: Well this is for an application I'm writing, so I need to be able to determine group membership, up to and including root. I'd also like it to be as portable as feasible.

Comment: Assume that group 0 is a real group but that it does not confer exalted privileges.  It provides a lot of power; some system directories belong to group 0 with write permission (the number is likely to vary dramatically between systems).  But although it is a corner case of sorts, you don't have to do anything special about it; just treat like you would any other group with a single-digit group ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity:

I still don't know why the `id -Gn` code works but not mine, but I think I fixed my own issue after a lot of back and forth. Basically I'm building a shared object and enumerating their current memberships by way of a helper program that uses `initgroups`/`getgroups` to set the running processes's (the helper executable) persona to the target user's default persona (what they would get after logging in. This is the full code of the helper program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct group *groupStruct;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        int numgroups, iter, retCode;
        int numgroups_max = sysconf(_SC_NGROUPS_MAX) + 1;
        gid_t groupList[numgroups_max];

        if (argc != 2){
                printf("Insufficient Arguments.\n");
                return 1;
        }

        retCode=initgroups(argv[1], 0);

        if (retCode != 0){
                printf("Unspecified failure: %d\n\n", retCode);
                return 1;
        }

        numgroups = getgroups(numgroups_max, groupList);

        for (iter=0; iter <= numgroups; iter++){

                if (iter != 0 &&  iter != numgroups )
                        printf(" ");

                  // "zero" means both "nothing more" and could be the root user's primary group, allow the first one through
                if ( groupList[iter] == 0 && getuid() == 0 ){
                        if ( iter != 0 )
                                break;

                }else if ( groupList[iter] == 0 )
                        break;


                printf("%d", groupList[iter]);

        }

        return 0;
}
```

Username is hard coded just for testing purposes. After compiling and testing it produces the group ID's for the user. Changing the hard coded value (or pushing it into argv) resolves the problem. I pushed this into a helper executable because it's changing the running process's persona (at least the group membership portion).

I'll probably move it into the library's calling routine for performance/security (I can save the supplementary and primary groups before with `getgroups` and `setgroups`), but it was quicker for me to do a proof of concept in a separate executable.

Comment: Your code should iterate over [0..numgroups). Zero as a group entry doesn't mean 'nothing more; it means the user belongs to group 0. It should appear at most once in the list of groups unless someone was careless in their use of `setgroups()`.  So the body of your printing loop should simply contain the initial `if` to print a blank and the final `printf()` (and the loop should be followed by a  `putchar('\n');` or equivalent).  And the loop should be `for (iter = 0; iter < numgroups; iter++)`.

Comment: "Zero as a group entry doesn't mean 'nothing more; it means the user belongs to group 0" I hate to disagree with you on that but that's incorrect. `getgroups` fills out the entire array you give it, whether it has that many supplementary groups or not. For example, the `jadavis6` account has two supplementary groups, but the third one returned by `getgroups` is gid 0. Not to mention I've compared the output of `id -G` with the output of this command and (with the exception of how it sorts) they're functionally identical, which wouldn't happen if I was ignoring memberships.

Comment: Also, it's a little overly prescriptive to tell me what the output of my own program ought to be. Not to mention it doesn't make sense to print a new line, as I said in the answer, it's a helper program underneath `/usr/libexec` that produces a string that is intended to get fed into `strtok` by the library function. Adding a new line is just adding random whitespace to what the library has to interpret.

Comment: At any rate, I think I worked out how to fix the zero gid problem. if you don't give it an array to store the result into, `getgroups` still does the group count and you can just allocate an array of that size to remove the ambiguity.